# Executing Python and Azure CLI on Windows local PC?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-sdk-python

What are the steps I must take in order to execute the Python script and Azure CLI on my Windows computer?

Script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberark/BlobHunter/main/BlobHunter.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure your local Python dev environment for Azure. One-time setup instructions to prep your machine would include:

- [Installing required components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd#install-components), namely an Azure account, Python, and the Azure CLI.
- [Configure authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd#configure-authentication) for when you use Azure libraries to provision, manage, and access Azure resources.
- Review the process of using [Python virtual environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd#use-python-virtual-environments) for each of your projects.

Once that is done, you can activate the virtual environment, `pip install` the libraries required by the referenced script, and then execute it with the following command:

```
py <script-name>.py
```

Check this article for detailed instructions and next steps: [Configure your local Python dev environment for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/configure-local-development-environment?tabs=cmd)

Comment: thank you for the response. Can I execute it under Visual Studio Code or this environment can only be using Terminal?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Of course yes, working with [Python in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python) is actually simple and fun! Check [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for getting started. :)